# Does haproxy have weight support

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

We are setting up a new server with some different configs and software versions of previous installations we have. This server will be connected to our haproxy server, but I want to limit/reduce the flow of traffic to the new server. Is it possible to add a weight value to a server in haproxy to accomplish this, or some other config setting to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does have weighting.

```
server smtp01 smtp01.example.com weight 45 check inter 15000
server smtp02 smtp02.example.com weight 45 check inter 15000
server smtp03 smtp03.example.com weight 10 check inter 15000
```

The example is for tcp proxy. That means it will send 10 smtp connections out of 100 when using a roundrubin balance. And before asking such a question, you should google it.

Comment: I did. And I found this page.